# Finding the values of dictionary while looping through a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that holds the data of employee and their attendance. I want to find the list of dates(might have 2 of the same date) that the record exists in the list and the dates that it does not exist.

```
attendance_list = [
{'employee_name': 'Bob', 'attendance_date': '2021-04-01', 'status': 'Present'}, 
{'employee_name': 'Bob', 'attendance_date': '2021-04-05', 'status': 'Present'}, 
{'employee_name': 'Bob', 'attendance_date': '2021-04-08', 'status': 'Half Day'}, 
{'employee_name': 'Bob', 'attendance_date': '2021-04-08', 'status': 'On Leave'}, 
{'employee_name': 'Bob', 'attendance_date': '2021-04-09', 'status': 'On Leave'}
]
```

Example: From 2021-04-01 to 2021-04-10

I thought of extracting the list of dates from the list and loop through the dates but how do I find the values of the dictionary inside ?

```
dates = ['2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-03', '2021-04-04', 
'2021-04-05', '2021-04-06', '2021-04-07', '2021-04-08', '2021-04-09', 
'2021-04-10']
attended_date = [d['attendance_date'] for d in attendance_list if 'attendance_date' in d]

for d in dates:
  if d not in attended_date:
    print("Not in List") 
  else:
    print("In List") #get the values of dict
```

Comment: try `if d['attendance_date'] not in attended_data:`

Comment: This is not clear at all.  You say that you're trying to get values from a dict, but your code doesn't refer to the dict at all.  Your `attended_date` list is a hand-crafted list of all the dates in the dict, and your loop logic is a questionable version of list intersection.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: My bad. I edited the `attended_date ` list

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the list you want is the dicts where the `attendance_date` is in `attended_date`. You can do this with list comprehension ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).

```
[
    attended_employee for attended_employee in attendance_list
    if attended_employee['attendance_date'] in attended_date
]
```